# MySQL information_schema.tables UPDATE_TIME refresh on specific column change with ANALYZE TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql, information-schema

Is it possible to update the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES UPDATE_TIME` for a specific table when a specific column is changed in this table?

I know that MySQL saves its cache to the `TABLES` on a timeout specified in the `information_schema_stats_expiry` variable and the timeout is 24h by default which is ok for me. Also I know I can query `ANALYZE TABLE 'table_name_1', ... 'table_name_N'` to force MySQL update the `TABLES`. But it will cause the update with no conditions. So is it possible to call `ANALYZE TABLE` only for specific columns? Thanks

Comment: nope. Can't do that. What are you trying to acheive at a high level.

Comment: I have a huge table that I need to cache in my application, but it is needed when the only few columns was changed

Comment: An update trigger could update a separate single row/column table (timestamp) on the condition that one column changes.